# How to run time-triggered Azure Function on IoTEdge

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a requirement in which I have to schedule a job to check for updates. I have to run a C# time-triggered function and deploy it as a module so that it can detect the change and pass the message to other modules via routing. I was unable to find any documentation.

I tried: [Deploy Azure Function on IoTEdge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function?view=iotedge-1.4)
But I wasn't able to change the trigger to a timer trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To run a time-triggered Azure Function on IoT Edge with the below steps.

1. Create a new Azure Function project in Visual Studio.
2. Add a new time-triggered function to the project.
3. Write the code for the function to check for updates.
4. Publish the function to a Docker container.
5. Create a new IoTEdge deployment manifest that includes the Azure Function module.
6. Deploy the IoTEdge deployment manifest to your IoTEdge device.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")] 
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) 
{ 
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}"); 
}
```

[Creating a time-triggered](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) Azure Function in C#.

Add the below NuGet package to your Azure Function project.
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EdgeHub`

This package provides the bindings for connecting to IoT Edge Hub.

To deploy the function as an IoTEdge module, you will need to publish it to a Docker container. You can use the `docker build` and `docker push` commands to build and push the container to a container registry.

Once you have the container image, you can create an IoTEdge deployment manifest that includes the Azure Function module.

```json
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {
              "myregistry": {
                "username": "<registry-username>",
                "password": "<registry-password>",
                "address": "<registry-address>"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": "{}"
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"5671/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"5671\"}],\"8883/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8883\"}],\"443/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"443\"}]}}}"
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "myFunction": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "<registry-address>/<function-image-name>:<function-image-tag>",
              "createOptions": "{}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "routes": {
          "myFunctionToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/myFunction/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Deploying the [Azure Function as an IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function?view=iotedge-1.4) module.

[image]

Once the module is deployed, it will start running the time-triggered function on a schedule that you have specified. The function will use the EdgeHub binding to send messages to other modules using the specified route name.

And to change the trigger to a timer trigger, you can use the `TimerTrigger` attribute in your C# code.

You can specify the schedule for the timer trigger using a `CRON expression` or a `TimeSpan value`.